# Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" when auto generating code with build_runner

Tags: flutter

After I have updated Flutter to v1.22 using code generation with `build_runner` was not working. I was told that the proper command to use in this version was:

`dart pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting outputs`

However, I receive the following error:

```sh
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\Users\jpiab\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\_fe_analyzer_shared-2.2.0".
```

I have no idea why it is looking for `pubspec.yaml` in that folder, since that folder is not the current working directory.

--- EDIT ---

The file exists in path:
`C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/_fe_analyzer_shared-2.2.0`

dart is just looking for it in the wrong place. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: You can `flutter` instead `dart` ?

Answer (score 28):

I solved for me. I use Android Studio in Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS.

Firstly run this command:

```
flutter pub get
```

After run this command:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

Or:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner watch
```

Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50092

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the .pub-cache folder.
and then run `pub get`

**Edit:**
If above method won't work then delete the folder

> C:\Users\jpiab\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org_fe_analyzer_shared-2.2.0

and then run `pub get` from within your project directory.

Comment: These two are the methods which i use

Comment: 1) flutter packages pub run builfuturebd_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

Comment: 2)  flutter pub run build_runner build

Comment: You have a spelling error in your "1)" at the package name ;)

Answer (score 1):

That same error I had and I resolved it by aligning my dependencies. Check if your build_runner is in the same line as flutter_test if you added it to dev_dependencies.

`Error Corrected`

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: [latest]
```

`My Error`

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
    build_runner: [latest]
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the environment variable PUB_CACHE to the right folder.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

**Make sure you run the `flutter` command from the project's root directory.**

As you can see, Running the command from a specific folder reproduces this error while everything works as expected from the project's root directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I was running the command

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build.yaml
```

instead of

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

After typing the command, I pressed tab and since the `build.yaml` file existed it auto appended `.yaml` to the command which I didn't notice.

After remove `.yaml` it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake is that my pubspec.yaml has a dependency point to another folder, which is the folder flutter tring to find pubspec, I changed it to a version, and it works good.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error I just deleted the `hosted` folder in this path `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted`,
And run `flutter doctor` will work perfectly.